# Get the product quantity in observer

Tags: product, event-observer, quantity

I am trying to get the product quantity in observer event `catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options` but even if i try to add more than one, the observer returns 1 as quantity

```
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

    $productqtty = $product->getQty();
```

**$productqtty** always returns 1

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

At this point the product object does not yet contain data for the cart item (qty, options).

But in the event you have access to the quantity through the buy request object:

```
$buyRequest = $observer->getEvent()->getBuyRequest();
$qty = $buyRequest->getQty();
```

#### Reference:

- core code where the event is dispatched: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d409dff20e992e97546568974399c456958299f9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php#L542-L546
- buyRequest explained:
  https://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/09/magento-info_buyrequest-objekt-referenz/ (this is my blog)

Comment: Thank you so much it is working in simple products but in grouped products  I still get 1 for quantity do you know what could be?

Comment: For grouped products each has its own qty. If you inspect the content of the buy request object you will find the individual qtys there

Comment: how could i check for each one the quantity in the observer? (as if they would be different products?) I need to limit the quantity of each product in a group product per customer)